# Cuda examples not working after cuda 8.0 install

Tags: nvidia, make, cuda

I got this error:

```
Makefile:381: recipe for target 'cudaDecodeGL' failed
make[1]: *** [cudaDecodeGL] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/michele/Desktop/NVIDIA_CUDA-8.0_Samples/3_Imaging/cudaDecodeGL'
Makefile:52: recipe for target '3_Imaging/cudaDecodeGL/Makefile.ph_build' failed
make: *** [3_Imaging/cudaDecodeGL/Makefile.ph_build] Error 2
```

Already try this solution:

```
sed -i "s/nvidia-367/nvidia-375/g" `grep "nvidia-367" -r ./ -l`
```

Not working... any guess?

Comment: What Ubuntu release are you using,  what error did you get, what Nvidia driver are you using, What exactly have you set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to?

Comment: Ubuntu : 16.0 .  The error is the one in the question.  nvidia-375. LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64:

Answer (score 1):

The change from nvidia-367 to nvidia-375 (the enabled Nvidia driver) should have been made in the .../NVIDIA_CUDA-8.0_Samples/3_Imaging/cudaDecodeGL/findgllib.mk file,  on line

```
UBUNTU_PKG_NAME = "nvidia-375"
```

With that change, the makefile should find the libnvcuvid library, which is the interesting part of the error.  My setup is just like yours and that's the only change I needed.

Try the "make" command in the cudaDecodeGL directory to see what exactly fails.