# Getting error when running CUDA sample after installing CUDA 8.0 in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, make, cuda

I just installed CUDA  8.0 in my Ubuntu 16.04

After installing I was trying to run samples but when I created dir NVIDIA_CUDA-8.0_Samples and ran the command `make`, I got this error

```
$make
```

...

```
nvcc warning : The 'compute_20', 'sm_20', and 'sm_21' architectures are deprecated, and may be removed in a future release (Use -Wno-deprecated-gpu-targets to suppress warning).
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lnvcuvid
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:381: recipe for target 'cudaDecodeGL' failed
make[1]: *** [cudaDecodeGL] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/mukesh/NVIDIA_DIR/NVIDIA_CUDA-8.0_Samples/3_Imaging/cudaDecodeGL'
Makefile:52: recipe for target '3_Imaging/cudaDecodeGL/Makefile.ph_build' failed
make: *** [3_Imaging/cudaDecodeGL/Makefile.ph_build] Error 2
```

then I searched for the error and I got a solution here:

[Failure in running CUDA sample after cuda 8.0 installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/891003/failure-in-running-cuda-sample-after-cuda-8-0-installation)

so I ran the command

```
~/NVIDIA_CUDA-8.0_Samples/$find . -type f -execdir sed -i 's/UBUNTU_PKG_NAME = "nvidia-367"/UBUNTU_PKG_NAME = "nvidia-375"/g' '{}' \;
```

After running this I again tried to run `make`, but still getting the error

```
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:270: recipe for target 'marchingCubes' failed
make[1]: *** [marchingCubes] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/mukesh/NVIDIA_DIR/NVIDIA_CUDA-8.0_Samples/2_Graphics/marchingCubes'
Makefile:52: recipe for target '2_Graphics/marchingCubes/Makefile.ph_build' failed
make: *** [2_Graphics/marchingCubes/Makefile.ph_build] Error 2
```

help me to get rid of it please.

thanks

Comment: thanks, but i am  bit confused. I think Nvidia driver is already there, I didn't installed any nvida driver at this time.
But I just tried to run    nvidia-smi   and it gave 
nvidia-smi: command not found

Comment: I was a bit confused too, the point is that the standard repository puts the driver in the location expected by the CUDA scripts, and any other install of Nvidia may not, even though it works fine as a video driver.  Further confusing things is the meta package business, so your 367 -> 375 edit was maybe needed if there were no libraries in the /usr/lib/nvivdia-367 directory.

Comment: In  Software and Updates -> Additional Drivers they are showing that 

[ Using Nvidia binary driver - version 375.66 from nvidia-375(propreitary, tested) ]

so I m not sure what should i do now. 
please guide

Comment: @ubfan1 i just checked that there is no such directory /usr/lib/nvivdia-367 , but there are directories like  /usr/lib/nvidia, /usr/lib/nvidia-375, /usr/lib/nvidia-375-prime. is this helpful in any way?

Comment: Sorry my typo.  The "missing" libraries should be in directory /usr/lib/nvidia-375.  The CUDA findgllib.mk files all reference nvidia-367, but only a few samples actually fail with that wrong name, which your blanket edit should fix.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall any nvidia drivers you have now, check that all the "blacklist nouveau" lines got removed from all files in /etc/modprobe.d, reboot and you should be using the nouveau drivers.  Now use the Software Updater to select the Nvidia 375.66 and when it finishes, reboot again, and you should be running that Nvidia driver.  Now a CUDA install (with the two recommeded PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH mods) will find the libraries it needs.  I'd uninstall the CUDA packages too, so you can reinstall them with the Nvidia in place, but try a compile before doing that.

---

Check that the "missing" libraries are actually in /usr/lib/nvidia-375.  Check that your .../cudaDecodeGL/findgllib.mk has the line

```
 UBUNTU_PKG_NAME = "nvidia-375"
```

Check that your PATH variable starts with /usr/local/cuda/bin:
and that your LS_LIBRARY_PATH starts with /usr/local/cuda/lib64
(or wherever you install cuda).  That  should be all that's necessary to run the make for cudaDecodeGL.  Many of the other samples do not even require this fix, like the marchingCubes.  If your link still can't pick up the library,
Check that /etc/ld.so.conf.d contains a file named cuda-8-0.conf with the contents of:

```
   /usr/local/cuda-8.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib
```

(or wherever instead of /usr/local you installed cuda).  That creation should have been automatic, the .deb file installation does it, can't say if other methods do.

Comment: thanks. but can you please give a reference that can help in a better way. I mean some time ago i tried to play with nouveau driver and my ubuntu get corrupted. I had to reinstall ubuntu again. I am feeling unsecure about that " Uninstall any nvidia drivers you have now, check that all the "blacklist nouveau" lines got removed from all files in /etc/modprobe.d " part.

Comment: search this site for "nvidia remove" and lots pop up.  I have to leave now, I'll check in later.